# Not showing texture after uv maping and importing png image?

Tags: modeling, texturing, uv

I am just learning blender..I made a 3d character and unwrapped it.. But when I opened the image in UV editing window it didn't show the any texture.

https://www.mediafire.com/folder/feo73886r4aer/character

[image: not showing texture to my 3 d model]

Answer (score 2):

I had to reload your image texture from disk to get it to show up. Once I did that I just changed the viewport mode from Solid to Textured and the textures appeared.

[image]

Comment: oh..soo silly mistake...thank you soo much...

Comment: No problem. If that solved your problem, please mark it as solved.